# How do I show the comment of the content from Django?

Tags: python, django, comments

I am use PostgreSQL on Django.
I am use Django 2.2.3 and pyton 3.7 version.

I want to display comments for related content. But all comments appear in all content.

I made the coding based on the narration found in the link(https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/homework_create_more_models/).

My codes:

views.py

```py
def PostDetail(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.filter(status=2, slug=slug)
    comment = Comment.objects.filter(approved_comment=True)
    comment_count = Comment.objects.count()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = post['id']
        print('hata: ', post_id)
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.Post = post
            new_comment.save()
            return redirect('blog:post_detail', slug)

    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, 'single-blog.html',
                  {
                      'post_details': post,
                      'comments': comment,
                      'comment_form': comment_form,
                      'comment_count': comment_count
                  }
                  )
```

models.py

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = HTMLField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    model_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', default='upload image')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    # reply_to = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='replies', null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    comment = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    comment_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', default='upload image')

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

single-blog.html

````html
<div class="comments-area">
                                            <h4>Comments:</h4>
                                            <div class="comment-list">
                                                {% for comment in comments %}
                        <div class="single-comment justify-content-between d-flex">
                          <div class="user justify-content-between d-flex">
                              <div class="thumb">
                                  <img src="img/blog/c1.png" alt="">
                              </div>
                              <div class="desc">
                                  <p class="comment">{{ comment.comment|linebreaks }}</p>
                                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                      <h5>
                                        <a href="#">{{ comment.author }}</a>
                                      </h5>
                                      <p class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</p>
                                    </div>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with your second line in the view, this

```
comment = Comment.objects.filter(approved_comment=True)
```

You are getting all comment with approved status True. While it should be,

```
post = Post.objects.get(status=2, slug=slug)   # notice the get instead of filter
comment = Comment.objects.filter(approved_comment=True, post=post)
```

So you filter on the comment related to the post you got in the line before.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But It's return this error "The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing."

Comment: Thats because your first line getting the post is a filter. Filter returns a queryset and not an exact lookup. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: You also need to check that the object exists before you try to filter with it. so a try/ excpet here around your post query could make sense.

Comment: Now it's return this error for post query 'Post' object is not iterable

Comment: Sorry and thanks for your help. I found the problem. I edited a faulty part of the template file.